# How do I enhance my rod?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I'm on chapter 14 now and I'm planning to use Umbra to go back and finish up side quests and max out everyone's skills, but I haven't gotten a single fishing rod upgrade. The last time I tried fishing (in Altissia, chapter 9, I think?), the fish were incredibly strong and if I even managed to catch one, it took about 10-15 minutes of intense angling. Typically, though, they just broke the line if I was a couple seconds late switching directions.

Considering how easy it was to catch fish early on, there's no way catching fish is supposed to be *this* hard, even if it's late in the game.

Did I miss some side quest to get a better rod? Do I randomly find them? Are they sold in stores? Where do I go/what do I do to get a better fishing rod?

Comment: I believe the quickest way to enhance your rod is go play Advent Children again and say hi to Tifa

Comment: I attempted to edit your title, but the edit was was declined (Guessing since it was a trivial edit). You might want to add the word fishing in there. At the moment, it sounds like a sexual innuendo

Comment: @Draken yeah, I didn't realize that rejecting an edit on my own post would automatically reject it. I was going to leave it up to other users to determine if it was necessary or not. If it's really a big deal, I'll go ahead and change it. I didn't think it was too bad.

Comment: @Vemonus Not to worry. I'm not the only one to see that though, as Alfie also has a dirty mind like me...

Comment: You're not alone having a dirty mind. I'm just finding it funny and click baity. Nothing wrong with it imo.

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre Or refuel at Hammerhead.

Comment: Oops I meant watch - I was going to type FFVII but changed my mind :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are four different components that are tied into upgrading your Fishing Pole, which are purchased at different Fishing Shops throughout the world.

[Fishing Guide](http://www.gameskinny.com/0i8hu/final-fantasy-xv-fishing-guide)

> **Fishing Equipment**
>
> 1. **Line** - Determines the durability of your fishing pole.
>      This is the HP of your pole. When it reaches 0, you will lose the line, lure, and won't catch the fish that bit.
> 2. **Lure** - This determines what fish will bite.
>      Each lure lists fish that it attracts, but they can also attract fish that are not listed.
> 3. **Rod** - This determines the defense of your pole.
>      The defense affects how fast your durability goes down when reeling in a fish.
> 4. **Reel** - This determines the attack of your pole.
>      The attack affects how fast you can reel in a fish.
>
> You start with all of these, but you can upgrade them by going to fishing shops.
>
> **Fishing Shops**
>
> 1. ***Galdin Quay*** - Bob's Bait Emporium: The first shop you will find is near the Galdin Quay. You can buy extra line and lures here.
> 2. ***Rachsia Bridge*** - Tabby's Tackle Shack: This shop is north of Old Lestallum. It sells more lines and lures, as well as a new rod and reel.
> 3. ***Vesper Pool East Bank*** - Bert's Bobbers 'n' Stuff: This shop sells the best line, Dragon's Beard, as well as some great lures and the best purchasable reel and rod.
> 4. ***Car***: You can also purchase lines and lures from your car as you progress through the game.

Comment: Ugh, why is fishing such an expensive hobby

Comment: Its also the most time consuming to level up IMO, as you have to ACTIVELY go level it. The other 3 level up just by playing the game.

Comment: I don't have the details at hand, but you can also get parts from quests or find them while exploring. I know I got a much better rod early on from a side quest.

Comment: Yeah, I got an extra rod from a quest (I'm afraid I can't say where at the moment) but it was one I found by noticing a quest question mark on my map and headed that way. Location was by a river obv.

Answer (score 0):

The best reel is won in the colosseum where you bid on monster fights, which is in alltissia. The best rod is won after you do all the fishing quests, I think there is four.